# How to resolve this error in android studio shows error on all the lines even after sync gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

My project worked perfect this error which occurred for me after my system get restarted unfortunately even though I have reinstalled Java and android studio even though I did't get solved what could be the solution.
[image: screenshot of MiUnion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding, cleaning project and or invalidate caches?

Build -> Clean Project
Build -> Rebuild Project

File -> Invalidate caches / Restart